# Idiomatic optional return values in C#

Tags: c#, swift

Coming from the Swift programming language, I've grown accustomed to the paradigm of [optional values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).  There are many cool aspects to this language feature, but one in particular that I am wondering if C# has an equivalent way of handling, which is `nil` function return values.  Take, for example, a simple lookup function that returns a value for a given key.  In Swift, the idiomatic way of handling a missing key would be to simply return `nil`.  In effect, this prevents programmers from having to throw errors or perform error handling in the vast majority of cases, and it works out quite elegantly.  Similarly, in Javascript, I might just return `undefined`.

From what I read on MSDN, it seems that the C# programmer would typically favor classical exceptions in such cases, and handle them in try catch blocks.  Is this generally the case?  Would it be unusual, for example, to wrap integer return values in a Nullable object and let the function caller check whether the value is null?  What would the orthodox approach for these situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions are for exceptional scenario's, not for regular program flow. I guess we're on the same side there.

You would only need an additional return "type" like `null` when your method both checks for availability *and* fetches the resource. Take for example the code to get the contents of a file:

```
if (File.Exists(...))
{
    return false;
}

string contents = File.ReadAllText(...);
...
return true;
```

This requires no exceptions or `null` return values, and if the file is deleted *between* checking and opening the file, that could then be considered an exceptional scenario.

However when trying to get an entity from the database, you'd want to combine the availability check and fetching the resource, so that only one query is required. There are alot of programmers that do in fact return `null`, but since there is no C# law it's hard to keep track of which method does what.

I personally like the `bool TryGet(int id, out Entity entity)` style, which clearly indicates it does an availability check and fetches the resource if found. If you prefer returning `null` and want to be more explicit about what your function does, you could use `Entity GetOrDefault(int id)` as a naming convention. Some framework methods (ie. [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)) are named that way.

In case of returning value types, returning a `Nullable<>` probably already states what your method is up to. To complete the circle, C# 7 will (as far as I know) add [non-nullable reference types](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/01/25/new-features-in-c-sharp-7-part-2/).

In the end it's up to you (and your team) what convention you prefer.

Comment: Thanks loads.  I especially appreciate the TryGet suggestion, that alone makes things much clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option type in C# (yet), in F# there's an option type which you could abuse in C#.

See here for a detailed description:
[Using F# option types in C#](http://langexplr.blogspot.de/2008/06/using-f-option-types-in-c.html)

or refer to C.Evenhuis post for the C# way to do it.